# Links posted on Facebook page do not show up

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, posting

I am working on a small module which needs to automatically post links on a Facebook page.
I have done the following setup:

- Created a Facebook page (the one who will display the links)
- Created a Facebook app
- Added the app both on the page administrator profile as well as on the Facebook page with the following permissions: publish_stream, manage_pages

In order to obtain a valid access token (manually for now - I know it is not recommended, but it does the job in my case) I have done the following:

1. Logged in as the page administrator
2. Navigate to the page: https: / / developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/
3. Copy the user token and make it non-transient by GET-ting the following url: https: / / graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app id}&client_secret={app secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token={the token which I copied earlier}
4. Get the page access token from the user token resulted from step 3 by firing a GET to: https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={the never expire access token}

From the json which I get after step 4 I copy the access token of the page which I am interested in and post the link with the following C# code:

```
try
        {
            dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();

            var fbm = message as FacebookMessage;

            data.access_token = ConnectionData.AuthenticationToken;
            data.message = fbm.Message;
            data.link = fbm.Link;
            data.name = fbm.Name;
            data.caption = fbm.Caption;
            data.description = fbm.Description;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fbm.Icon))
            {
                data.picture = fbm.Icon;
            }
            var @params = ((ExpandoObject)data).ToUrl();

            var _currentRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/feed?{1}", _currentEndpoint.ObjectID, @params));
            _currentRequest.Method = "POST";
            _currentRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            _currentRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Windows NT)";
            _currentRequest.Accept = "*/*";
            _currentRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            _currentRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            //_currentRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            //using (var sw = new StreamWriter(_currentRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            //{
            //    sw.Write(json);
            //}

            string json;
            var resp = _currentRequest.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var jsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            var output = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

            return new OperationStatus();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new OperationStatus { Exception = ex };
        }
    }
```

The "_currentEndpoint.ObjectID" is the Object ID of the page.
The POST is done successful, and I see the link being posted both on my administrator's wall as well as on the Page itself as long as I am logged in as admin.
The sooner I log out, I can't see any posted links nor anyone else who liked the page.

What gives? How can I make the links to show up on the page wall and also on the walls of the people who liked the page.
I did check spam on the page, and I don't see my links there, and from the privacy settings everything seems visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this post: [Posting a link to a page not showing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213682/posting-a-link-to-a-page-not-showing-up) I finally got it up and running. The problem seem to have been with the access token, but I still haven't figured out what went wrong:
Here is what I did in the end:

- went to Graph API explorer http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
- fired a GET to me/accounts
- as a response I got the list of available accounts (including the one for my app)
- took the access token from that response.

That seem to have provided me the access token I needed to post visible links to everyone on the page wall.